# How to use jQuery .has() within a nested table

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to color a td cell that has a nested table with the class "red".  The jQuery code I'm using will color the top most table, not the parent td cell.  How do I need to modify the following code.

And as a little reference, I'm using SharePoint which nests tables within table within tables.  I don't have control over that unfortunately.

Thanks

```
$("td:has(.red)").addClass("redBG");
```

Comment: `$('.red').closest('td').addClass('redBG')` should be ok (looking reverse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go reverse order: find table with class `red`, than add class `redBG` to closest `td` cell:

```
$('table.red').closest('td').addClass('redBG');
```

This is rather the solution, but actually not an answer to your question.

For jQuery [closest method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) we have:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.